# Old HTTP requests arrive to server behind AWS ELB

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

We had an interesting event the other day in our system where a burst of month old HTTP requests arrived to our ELB and from there to one of our coupled servers. We could tell that the requests were old by a timestamp we are sending from our client app (and from the fact it had no relevant data :) ).

Our system is hosted on AWS, using a group of EC2 instances behind an ELB which communicates in HTTP with the EC2's. Also, our client app runs on iOS.

A thing to notice - the old requests were dated to a day in which we had a server crash which lead to a great load on our remaining servers (resulting in a lot of hanged HTTP requests, i.e they were not processed)

Also, despite the group of old messages originally spanned across several minutes (which we know from the timestamps), they all came in a single bulk the other day (this is from the ELB metrics).

We are trying to figure out how or where could these requests stack up and maybe understand why it happened when it did.
Any insights, similar experiences or suggestions will be appreciated as we've failed to find similar events on the web, thanks!

Comment: what does the architecture look like? where are these requests coming from? i'm guessing the servers are part of some form of webservice?

Comment: I'm sorry - requests are coming from a client app written over iOS. All transport (from multiple clients) is directed to our ELB. ELB routes requests over HTTP to EC2 instences

Comment: this is fascinating:) no ideea for now but I'll return if I think of something.